# Proving that an $n\times n$ matrix is positive definite iff the eigenvalues of that matrix plus its transpose are positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is positive definite iff the eigenvalues of $(A + A^T)$ are positive.

So far I have:

Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $(A + A^T)$ and let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue associated with $x$

$(A + A^T)x = \lambda x$

$x^T(A + A^T)x = \lambda ||x||^2$

I know this proves that $(A + A^T)$ is positive definite, but I'm not sure how to go from that to proving that $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: What do you mean the eigenvalues are positive definite?

Comment: @vounoo Oh, whoops, I meant positive. I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
x^TAx= \frac 12 x^T(A+A^T)x
$$

---

**Proof:** Note that $x^TAx$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix.  It follows that
$$
x^TAx = [x^TAx]^T = x^TA^Tx
$$
It then follows that
$$
x^TAx + x^TAx = x^TAx + x^TA^Tx
$$
Which is to say that
$$
2x^TAx = x^T(A + A^T)x
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Hmm, is there a proof for that formula?

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Okay, I think I understand. I'm still a little confused though, by how to prove that $x^TAx= \frac 12 x^T(A+A^T)x$

Comment: I proved that
$$
x^TAx - \frac 12 x^T(A+A^T)x = 0
$$
in my proof above.  Is there a step in the proof that you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: I came up with a quicker proof.  See if this one makes sense to you.

Comment: @Okay, now I get it. Thanks a lot!